# Object creation error

Tags: c++, oop

I am a complete c++ noob. Start to learn it from the java. So, after hard study with some tutorials, I ended up with this class named Token:

```
#include "Token.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//int Token::frequency = 0;



Token::Token() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    frequency=0;
    tok = "hey i am created";
    cout << tok << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

}

Token::~Token() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

The header for this class is this:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H_
#define TOKEN_H_
#include <string>

class Token {
    std::string tok;
    int frequency;
public:
    Token();
    virtual ~Token();
};

#endif /* TOKEN_H_ */
```

It looks like in the tutorial, all right. The error is when I called it in my main class:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H_
#define TOKEN_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Token myToken;
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
#endif /* TOKEN_H_ */
```

The error says :

> Tokenizer.cpp:15:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘myToken’

Whyyy? I looked up the tutorials and answers here, it looks like I am doing it right? What is going on? And, if you see that I did some other crap, pls tell me, I will be thankful, I just came from Java to C++...

Comment: If you're committed to learning C++ you really, really need a solid C++ reference book or you're going to drown in details. Tutorials will only get you so far. At the very least, the [Bjarne book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) is a must have, and there are others that you may find helpful if you have a Java background.

Comment: Developing a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a valuable skill in any language. In this case it would have revealed to you that this problem has nothing to do with object creation.

Comment: downwoting is nice, but I cant see why yet, so mister who downvote my question, at least tell me comment why you did this. I provided all the details and such, did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `#ifndef TOKEN_H_` around your `main` function, which makes no sense. That `#ifndef` is called a *header guard*, and it's used to protected headers from being included multiple times. Your main function should go into a source file (.c or .cpp or the like). You do not need header guards in source files since they aren't included from other source files.

You need your main.cpp file to be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "token.h"
// other stuff, like the using namespace

int main() { /* then your main function. */ }
```

Actually, most of your source files will follow this sort of pattern. This is the same pattern your Token.cpp file is built with.

Comment: why it doen't make any sense? I want to include token into some other file later and I dont want error because of that/

Comment: @Ophelia You can't use any declarations from Token.h (i.e. `Token`) without including Token.h...

Comment: I updated the answer to explain why it doesn't make sense to use header guards in source files.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the actual header for your class

```
#include "Token.h"
```

That way the class definition is available and you can declare an instance of `Token` in `main`

These are header/include guards, you don't need them in your main file

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H_
#define TOKEN_H_
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not incluiding the token header `#include "token.h"`, thus, the compiler think that `Token myToken;` is a definition not a declaration, also you don't need the header guards

Answer (score 0):

remove the `#ifndef` guards from the main.c file. Also include the `Token.h` header in main.

Comment: That is true, it needs to include "token.h" also, I just saw your answer. Down vote really?

Comment: Ok fair enough. Fixed it.